# Injecting commands into a background task

Tags: ubuntu, minecraft-forge, background-task

I'll try to explain as much as I can my issue.
So I have an Ubuntu machine set up which I use to host my Minecraft Server. It uses Java 8.
To start it, I usually use the command `java -Xmx10G -jar server.jar nogui`. But as I am going on vacation and my friends still want to sometimes play on it, I wanted to make an option to start it without having to enter this command. I created a .sh file, put it as crontask and put this in it :

`nohup sudo java -Xmx10G -jar server.jar nogui >> minecraft_logs.txt &`

This line works fine, and my server is running in background, printing its output in "minecraft_logs.txt". However, I realized I couldn't have access to its console anymore. I however wanted to be able to send commands on it (inputs), such as tellraws or give commands.

How could I "inject" commands into my Minecraft Server task running in the background ? Thank you.

I tried using screen or using this syntax :
`nohup sudo java -Xmx10G -jar server.jar nogui < input.txt >> minecraft_logs.txt &`
but it didn't work at all. I couldn't find anything that worked for me.

Comment: `Screen` should do what you're after. You'll get better answers from [superuser](https://superuser.com/), as this isn't a programming question.

Comment: @Lucan Thank you for your reply! I'll try to look into Screen and maybe ask my question in the forum provided if I can't get it to work. Thanks!